# Upload .txt file to Dropbox without saving locally first

Tags: python, filesystems, dropbox, dropbox-api

I have a .txt file that I need to upload into a Dropbox folder. On my PC it works great as it is however I need to put the code into a Google Cloud Function and as the GCP file system is read-only - this method if failing.

Can anyone recommend an alternative way of doing this that doesn't require me to save the data locally before pushing it up into Dropbox?

Here is my current working code for my local version:

```
import pathlib
import dropbox

api_key = 'XXXXXXXXXX'

# Build String And Save Locally To File
string = ["Item_A","Item_B","Item_C","Item_D"]
string = str(string)
with open('Item_List.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write(string)

# Define Local File Path
localfolder = pathlib.Path(".")
localpath = localfolder / 'Item_List.txt'

# Define Dropbox Target Location
targetfile = '/Data/' + 'Item_List.txt'

# Initilize Dropbox
d = dropbox.Dropbox(api_key)

# Upload File To Dropbox
with localpath.open("rb") as f:
    d.files_upload(f.read(), targetfile, mode=dropbox.files.WriteMode("overwrite"))
```

Comment: it seems that you could use [`io.StringIO`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.StringIO) since it supports `write` and `read` methods

Comment: @Matiiss turning it to bytes worked a treat. Do you want to post it as an answer so I can accept it? :)

Comment: You created a text file, but when uploading it, you're reading it as a binary file. You might not need to convert it to bytes if you opened it as text file (i.e. leave the `b` put of the `'rb'`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to simply use byte data, you can use the [built-in `bytes` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-bytes) to convert a string to byte data (you need to also specify encoding):

```py
data = ["Item_A", "Item_B", "Item_C", "Item_D"]
string_data = str(data)
byte_data = bytes(string_data, encoding='utf-8')
```

And then later just use the byte data as the argument:

```py
d.files_upload(byte_data, targetfile, mode=dropbox.files.WriteMode("overwrite"))
```